# Different classes for wordpress sub-menus

Tags: wordpress, submenu, depth

I'm using Wordpress' [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to display my main navigation. 
Trying to recreate the following piece of HTML in wordpress however seems quite complicated.

[image: front end menu]

Here is the HTML version (classes in the wordpress stylesheet have been adjusted to target the ones wordpress uses):

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Store</a>
    <div class="subnav">
        <div class="holder">
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a>
                    <ul class="grandchild">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-category 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a>
                    <ul class="grandchild">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-category 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-category 2</a></li>
                    </ul> <!-- Grandchild -->
                </li>
            </ul> <!-- Child nav -->
        </div> <!-- Holder -->
    </div> <!-- Subnav -->
</li></ul><!-- nav -->
```

What the problem in wordpress is that I used a walker to add the div around my first sub-menu that keeps everything in place. This way though, it adds the 2 divs (subnav and holder) to every sub-menu following.

How can I edit the next depth level to 
- not add the 2 divs
- edit the class name of the sub-menu

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"subnav\" ><div class=\"holder\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";

function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "$indent</ul></div></div>\n";
```

Comment: Also stuck. Are you missing the $item argument from the start_lvl() function?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to add classes to the submenus to target them with CSS?  Can't you just do something like this:

```
#nav > li a {
    /* Target first level */
}

#nav > li > ul > li a {
    /* Target second level */
}

#nav > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
    /* Target third level */
}​
```

Here's a jsfiddle illustrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/3XtkE/